# Highcharts Data and Point not align

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I try to create charts using highcharts, I try to set default poinstart then set pointInterval but this setting cause charts data and point not align properly.

How to setup pointstart & pointinterval to make data & point align?

This is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/dr5utk7s/32/

```
var chartSeriesData=[];
var chartCatData=[];
var power=[48,50,56,57,58,59,62,69];
var time=['04:30','04:30','04:30','04:31','04:31','04:34','04:36','04:40'];

    var hour = time[0].substring(0,2);
var minute = time[0].slice(-2);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {text: ''},
                    subtitle: {text: ''},

                    yAxis: {
                    },
                    xAxis: [{
                        type: 'datetime',
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        labels: {
                          format: '{value:%H:%M}',
                        }
                        
                    }],

                    series: [
                        
                        {
                            name: ' ',
                            data: power,
                            pointStart: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, hour, minute),
                            pointInterval: 1500 * 1000
                        }
                    ]
  }

);
```

The result I get
[image]

I want the xaxis only show interval 30 minutes from start time but align to yaxis

If I use pointinterval xaxis not align to yaxis

Comment: Inferring from the fiddle, it seems the chart works correctly. You are setting the `pointStart` to 4:30:00 and adding `pointInterval` to a half minute. What would you like to achieve? If you want to set `time` as xAxis data, you can set it as categories: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o4agrkcz/

Comment: Hi @magdalena, Thanks for your help. I update my question

Comment: Is the interval shouldn't be 1800 * 1000, if you want to set it to 30 minutes? The points and ticks are aligned then: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q3bs4vme/